# How to query for a particular foreign record in django models

Tags: django, django-models

Given these models:

```
class Cluster(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()


class Vmt(models.Model):
    added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, blank=True, null=True)
    purpose = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(Cluster, null=True)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("cluster", "added"),)
```

I would like to be able to have a result set that only contains Vmt records that were 'added' today.

I have tried this:

```
for c in Cluster.objects.filter(vmt__added='2018-06-18'):
    print "%s Vmt count = %s" % (c.name, c.vmt_set.count())
    for vmt in c.vmt_set.all():
        print "vmt added %s" % (vmt.added)
```

But I get results that look like this:

```
GL-AURM24 Vmt count = 2
vmt added 2018-06-18
vmt added 2018-06-17
GL-AURM23 Vmt count = 2
vmt added 2018-06-18
vmt added 2018-06-17
JCK-AURM10 Vmt count = 2
vmt added 2018-06-18
vmt added 2018-06-17
```

I was hoping for:

```
GL-AURM24 Vmt count = 1
vmt added 2018-06-18
GL-AURM23 Vmt count = 1
vmt added 2018-06-18
JCK-AURM10 Vmt count = 1
vmt added 2018-06-18
```

This SQL produces the results I want:

```
select 
      c.name, 
      v.added 
from 
      vc_cluster c, 
      vmt_vmt v 
where 
     v.cluster_id = c.id 
     and v.added = '2018-06-18';
```

How to I write that SQL in a Django query?

Comment: So with *added* you mean that the first date of that record is today?

Comment: added is the date the data was gathered from an external source.  I'd like to be able to track a history of the Vmt data overtime and would also like to be able to single out particular days.

Comment: I would also like to be able to query for a date range.

Comment: but when is something in the range? If it the first record is in that range, or *any* record is in that range?

Comment: a date range like all records that where added on 2018-01-01 through 2018-02-15.

Comment: so you want to filter on `Vmt`s, right? Not `Cluster`s then?

Comment: I would like to be able generate a list of all clusters with their vmt records for a given date.

Comment: Well then you replace the `for vmt in c.vmt_set.all():` with `for vmt in c.vmt_set.all(added__range=(date(2018,1,1), date(2018,2,15))):` The same for the `.count()`.

Comment: Maybe if I post the SQL that gives me the result I am looking for you can help me out in writing the equivalent dejango query.

Answer (score 0):

for c in Cluster.objects.filter(vmt__added='2018-06-18'):
    print "%s Vmt count = %s" % (c.name, c.vmt_set.filter(vmt__added='2018-06-18').count())
    for vmt in c.vmt_set.filter(vmt__added='2018-06-18'):
        print "vmt added %s" % (vmt.added)

### Cluster.objects.filter(vmt__added='2018-06-18')

Return all cluster with at least one vmt added the 2018-06-18

### c.vmt_set.all()

Return all vmt associated to c. It's a new query.